# Grep and returning only column of match

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep, multiple-columns

if i want to search from a file with various number of columns like this:

```
ppl:apple    age:5    F    add:blabla    love:dog
ppl:tom    M    add:blablaa    love:cat
ppl:jay    age:3    M    love:apple
ppl:jenny    acc:jen    age:8   F   add:blabla

...
```

the file is tab separated, and the output i want is:

```
age:5
age:3
age:8
...
```

using `grep age:` will return the entire row, while
using `cut -f2` will return some unwanted column:

```
age:5
M
age:3
acc:jen
```

and neither `cut -f2|grep age:` nor `grep age|cut -f2:` work

My data may range from 11-23 columns, 
will there be any simpler way to handle it using grep sed or awk, 
many thanks

Comment: The input you have given, the second line does not have age:x . Is input data like this.

Comment: replace the T in this with a tab: `sed -n "s/^.*T\(age:[^T]*\)T*$/\1/p" < x.txt`

Comment: some might not have the age: column, the total number of column is not fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`grep` itself can do this, with no additional tools, by using the `-o`/`--only-matching` switch. You should be able to just do:

```
grep -o '\<age:[0-9]\+'
```

To explain the less common parts of the regex:

- `\<` is a zero-width assertion that you're at the beginning of a word (that is, age is preceded by a non-word character or occurs at the beginning of the line, but it's not actually matching that non-word character); this prevents you from matching, say `image:123`. It doesn't technically require whitespace, so it would match `:age:` or the like; if that's a problem, match `\t` itself and use `cut` or `tr` to remove it later.
- `\+` means "match 1 or more occurrences of the preceding character class" (which is `[0-9]`, so it matches one or more digits). `\+` is equivalent to repeating the class twice, with the second copy followed by `*`, e.g. `[0-9][0-9]*`, except it's shorter, and some regex engines can optimize `\+` better.

Comment: ++; indeed the simplest approach. While not POSIX-compliant, it works with both GNU and BSD/OSX `grep`. (`-o` is a nonstandard option, and POSIX EREs do not support `\<` or any other kind of word-boundary assertion).

Comment: @mklement0: Thanks for the portability note. Couldn't find the POSIX `grep` spec. The `\<` is mostly for safety; it could be omitted if substrings of that form wouldn't occur (don't want to match `image:` for instance), or you could match on `\t` instead of `\<` and use `cut` to remove the `\t` from the result.

Comment: simplest for my case! tks
may i ask about that '\<\+'

Comment: You can find the POSIX `grep` spec [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html). Matching `\t` would be slightly more robust given the requirements, but `\<` will probably do, especially if it saves you a separate command. With _GNU_ `grep` you could get the best of both worlds: `grep -Po '\t\Kage:[0-9]+' file`

Comment: @once: `\<` is a zero-width assertion that you're at the beginning of a word (that is, `age` is preceded by a non-word character or occurs at the beginning of the line, but it's not actually matching that non-word character), `\+` means "match 1 or more occurrences of the preceding character class" (which is `[0-9]`, so it matches one or more digits). `\+` is equivalent to repeating the class twice, with the second copy followed by `*`, e.g. `[0-9][0-9]*`, except it's shorter, and some regex engines can optimize `\+` better.

Comment: @mklement0: Yar, I usually go for fixed strings with `fgrep` or PCRE regexes with `grep -P`, because POSIX regexes (basic and extended) are just a PITA. I tried to stick to plain `grep` in this case largely to minimize portability issues (though obviously, I still used a couple non-strict POSIX extensions, oops).

Comment: @ShadowRanger: Got it; yes, `-P` is great; sadly, not available in the BSD/OSX implementation.

Comment: A final note re POSIX: `\+` is a GNU extension to BREs that is also not POSIX-compliant (to emulate it in a standards-compliant fashion necessitates the ungainly `\{1,\}`); to my surprise, BSD/OSX _does_ support it, however, unlike most other BSD utilities.

Answer (score 2):

You can use script below:

```
cat file|grep age|awk '{for(i=1;i<22;i++){if($i ~ /^age:/)print $i}}'
```

Answer (score 1):

<sup>[ShadowRanger's simple `grep`-based answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35763054/45375) is probably the best choice.</sup>

A solution that works with both GNU `sed` and BSD/OSX `sed`:

```
sed -nE 's/^.*[[:blank:]](age:[0-9]+).*$/\1/p' file
```

With *GNU* `sed` you can simplify to:

```
sed -nr 's/^.*\t(age:[0-9]+).*$/\1/p' file
```

Both commands match the entire input line, if it contains an `age:` field of interest, replace it with that captured field (`\1`), and print the result; other lines are ignored.

---

Original answer, before the requirements were clarified:

Assuming that on lines where `age:` *is* present, it is always the *2nd* tab-separated field, `awk` is the best solution:

```
awk '$2 ~ /^age:/ { print $2 }' file
```

- `$2 ~ /^age:/` only matches lines whose 2nd whitespace-separate field starts with literal `age:`
- `{ print $2 }` simply prints that field.

Comment: @once: Got it. Please clarify such a requirement up front next time.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use sed

```
    sed -nr 's/^.*(age:.).*$/\1/p'  input_pattern.txt
```

Where input_pattern.txt contains you data.

Answer (score 1):

Limit search for regexp to columns 11 to 23:

```
awk '{ for(i = 11; i <= 23; i++) { if ($i ~ /^age:/) print $i } }' file
```